# IOS 10.1.1 Untrusted Enterprise Developer error

Tags: ios

I downloaded a few apps from a third party website, and the apps are perfectly functional for the first couple days and then I get the Untrusted Enterprise Developer error again. I go into my General->Device management and attempt to trust the apps once more, but there is only an option to delete or verify apps. I notice that all of the apps are unverified, so when I attempt to verify the apps, it acts like its about verify-but nothing gets verified. By this point I can either press Verify apps again, or press Delete apps. If I press verify apps again same result. How do I get my apps running again?! Please help.!

Comment: I came here because I can't seem to get a decent answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I found that deleting the app via settings>general>device management>APP, then reinstalling, fixed the issue for me.